# English words hyphenation in Russian text

Tags: latex

I have multi-lingual TeX document mostly in Russian but I also include some terms in English in brackets too to make the reader familiar with international terminology. For example the phrase

> Два неотъемлемых свойства языка
>   программирования - *синтаксис* (*syntax*)
>   и *семантика* (*semantics*).

which simply means

> Two attributes of a programming
>   language are its syntax and semantics.

looks like

> Два неотъемлемых свойства языка
>   программирования ---
>   \textit{синтаксис}
>   (\textit{\selectlanguage{english}syntax\selectlanguage{russian}})
>   и \textit{семантика}
>   (\textit{\selectlanguage{english}semantics\selectlanguage{russian}}).

Also I have \usepackage[english,russian]{babel}.

The code looks too verbose because I need to use \selectlanguage twice on each English word to make hyphenation work. Without this I get a couple of

> Overfull \hbox ...

messages because TeX is not able to hyphen English words when they appear at the ends of the lines.

**Is there any better solution?**

---

**In response to Alexey Malistov.**

MacTeX distribution has a couple of language.dat files

- /usr/local/texlive/2009/texmf-dist/source/generic/babel
- /usr/local/texlive/2009/texmf-dist/doc/generic/babel
- /usr/local/texlive/2009/texmf/tex/generic/config
- /usr/local/texlive/2009/texmf-var/tex/generic/config
- /usr/local/texlive/2009/texmf-dist/tex/lambda/config

I'm not sure which one should I edit. Probably one of the first two. They are identical

```
% File    : language.dat
% Purpose : specify which hypenation patterns to load 
%           while running iniTeX 
=USenglish
american ushyphen.tex
=english
UKenglish  ukhyphen.tex
=british
french   frhyphen.tex
dutch    nehyph2.tex
german   dehypht.tex 
ngerman  dehyphn.tex
```

But which one?

Also there is no initexmf command. Googling around I found out that analogue is updmap-sys. But I'm not sure... I'm afraid to spoil my TeX installation. Please, give me the right direction.

Comment: I think all files `language.dat` must be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `\selectlanguage{}` twice because is a switch, you can use either the `otherlanguage` environment, or the `\foreighlanguage` macro:

```
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
   Hello world
\end{otherlanguage}
```

Or, for inline changes like in your example:

```
Два неотъемлемых свойства языка программирования --- \emph{синтаксис}
(\foreignlanguage{english}{\emph{syntax}}) и \emph{семантика}
(\foreignlanguage{english}{\emph{semantics}}).
```

In fact, if you often give the english terms, you can define a macro:

```
\newcommand{\englishterm}[1]{%
    \foreignlanguage{english}{\emph{#1}}}
```

Comment: Finally I accepted this answer. By the way probably something is wrong with macro. In my case working example looks like \newcommand{\englishterm}[1]{\foreignlanguage{english}{\emph{#1}}}. Anyway thanks for mentioning \foreignlanguage and macro. And another thing for people having the same problem: \sloppy command may be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

You should combine english and russian hyphens.
Change the file language.dat, adding the following:

```
ruseng ruenhyph
=russian
=english
```

And recompile all format files:

```
initexmf --dump
```

**Add**

I use MikTeX. I do not know what you have to do exactly. I would try and experiment.

1. You should add "new language ruseng" which contains english and russian hypens. Then no `\setlanguage` macro is needed. It works for me very well. I use russian and english words and do not use `\setlanguage`.
2. You should recompile your formats file. `MikTeX` provides `initexmf` command. I am sure there is similiar command for your MacTeX.

Comment: Ooops. I didn't mention that I use MacTeX. Sorry for that. I added some info to my message.

Comment: Finally I made it. The command which I used was "sudo texconfig init". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add discretionary hyphens (`\-`) on every english word as appropriate.

Alternatively, you can define your own environment that handles both the `textit` and the language selection.

Comment: +1: But why an environment? The Qn cites usages in horizontal mode; `\def\russeng#1#2{#1(\textit{\selectlanguage{english}syntax\selectlanguage{russian}})}` will do the trick much less cumbersomely.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `\selectlanguage` should follow the usual scope rules, so that you can enclose the part you want to be english in braces, which delimit a local scope:

```
Два неотъемлемых свойства языка программирования --- \textit{синтаксис} 
({\textit{\selectlanguage{english}syntax}}) и \textit{семантика}
({\textit{\selectlanguage{english}semantics}}).
```

I can't test this right now, though, so if you find that it doesn't work, I would be glad if you informed me of the fact, so that I can modify or delete this answer.